# How to switch to container session when lost connection with redis as using spring-shiro sessionManager with redis

Tags: session, session-state, shiro, spring-session

I am using spring-shiro sessionManager with redis.

If the redis don't work or just lost connection with redis, DefaultWebSessionManager of shiro can't CRUD session. I hope I can switch to use container session when this happen.

Is there sth like memcached-session-manager that can also using web container session?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom SessionManager for this.

This gets complicated pretty quickly depending on how you want to fail over, You would lose cluster support, which would probably require you to start using sticky sessions (or something similar).

Have you looked into making Redis fault tolerant instead?

Comment: thanks for your reply.   When I can not connect to the redis server which is the worst case I also want keep the application available, Although the cluster session down grade to  sticky session. Even I use redis cluster it still can't avoid network failure. So as your suggestion I should implement custom SessionManager for failover to sticky session. Is there any out of the box solution for shiro, like memcached-session-manager?

Comment: There is this one, but it is a little dated: https://github.com/mythfish/shiro-memcached but it could be a starting point for you

Comment: Thank you for help, this could give me some ideas.